# Where can I find the original Ubuntu logo files of various versions?

Tags: logo

I saw somewhere logo files just like the PNG file in `/lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.pn` but much bigger. Where can I download them?

Answer (score 1):

It would have been nice, if you had actually shown the image you are looking for, because I do not have that file on my computer!

But assuming that the title of your question is correct, then the [Ubuntu logos are here](http://design.ubuntu.com/downloads?metadata=element-logo+brand-ubuntu). If you need a large version, just download the svg and create your own png with the size you need.

There is also an [explanation about how to use the logos](http://design.ubuntu.com/assets/ubuntu-logo).